# Google Font Not Showing Up In IE8

Tags: css, google-font-api

Apparently the font "Arvo" is supposed to work fine in IE, but I can't get it to show up. This is my css:

```
body {
background: #000 url(../imgs/black_denim.png) repeat center top;
font-family: 'Arvo', Arvo, serif;
font-family: 17px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Works fine in all other browsers, at http://www.johnshammas.com/new. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the proper css to pull the fonts in: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: Yep, it works fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`font-family: 17px;` should be `font-size: 17px;`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems google fonts support all browser. Checkout the link below that might be helpful.
https://developers.google.com/webfonts/faq#Browsers_Supported